# Expand text with animation limited by overflow and ellipsis css proprieties

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, overflow, ellipsis

I was trying to apply an animation on two state on a `<p>text</p>` html element.
This text is truncate by some css proprieties :

**First state**

```
 white-space: nowrap;     /* Do not go to line if text is multiline */
 width: 300px;            /* The text cannot be larger than 300px */
 overflow: hidden;        /* If it's larger than 300px => not show the rest */
 text-overflow: ellipsis; /* add '...' after the text if it is larger than 150px */
```

**Second state**

```
 word-wrap: break-word;   /* only force word to be one multiple line if it is larger than 300px */
 width: 300px;
```

So how can i animate the first state to the second state ? (and vice versa)

Here is a plunker of the code i will animate. It can be animated with angular or angular material or pur css.

[My Plunker for test](https://plnkr.co/edit/DUdFVzVrAaKtosppTBHf)

Thanks =)

Comment: Basically, `text-overflow` can't be animated so you may have to rethink your strategy. It's either on...or off.

Comment: Ok, that's sad.